# Update resource file of my eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My plugin uses a resource file inside it's jar.
However during runtime I want to update this resource therefore I'm looking for a way to write some content into this file.

So far I got the `URL` to my resource file, but as it is in a jar I can't use a `File` to access it.
Therefore I tried

```
URLConnection connection = resourceURL.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();

OutputStream resourceOut = connection.getOutputStream();
```

But this thows me a `UnknownServiceException` stating that this protocol does not support an `OutputStream`.

I did some research on the web but I couldn't find an answer to my problem. I hope someone has an idea on how to update the content of my resource file.

Comment: Why do you want to update a file that is in a jar? How are you going to guarantee you have write permissions on the .jar to update it? A resource in a .jar should provide default values, and then store the updated values in a file externally. If you are using eclipse, consider using the preferences system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write to the plug-in jar. On some platforms this will be installed in a read only location.

If you want to change data associated with a plug-in I suggest you put it in the plug-in 'state location'. This is a directory in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins` directory reserved for your plug-in.

Get the state location using:

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());

IPath stateLoc = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

You can put anything you like in this directory. It is up to your plug-in to manage the contents.